# Why don't you need to unwrap an optional type value when being set?

Tags: swift, option-type

Does it mean that the set operation doesn't read the actual value of the Optional, so it doesn't need to be unwrapped?

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

class Base{
    var name:String?
};

var obj = Base()
obj.name = "hello" //this line don't need unwrapping first
```

Comment: This is Swift, don't use semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: Plus, as per Swift naming convention you should make class names capitalized: `base` –> `Base`

Comment: An optional has a value or it's `nil`. You can assign both. And unwrapping a literal is illogical anyway.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks , I am just new to swift , i will do it more 'swifty' way :)

Comment: optionals can get both nil or any data ,so when you assign them some value, its ok, there is no need to check if its not nil, we unwrap optionals to make sure they are not nil , why should we make sure whether it is nil or not when we just want to assign a new value to it ?? but when you write ` if let constantName = some Optional` you are not assigning any new value to your optional, you are in fact saying "hey, if  some Optional is not nil, pour its value into constantName!" so here you are reading your optional's value , you are not writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *optional* is a box. The box can either contain nothing (which is called `nil`) or it can contain something of a specific type (a `String` in your example). You unwrap an *optional* to access the value inside in the box.

When you are assigning a value to an *optional*, you just need to assign the value to the box itself. There is no need to unwrap anything, because you are just putting a value into the box. Swift either empties the box, if you assign `nil`, or it wraps the value by putting it into the box.

Unwrapping is for accessing a value that is already in the box.

---

Answering your question from a comment on another answer...

> But why Optional binding don't need unwrapping? i think i if let constantName = some Optional is kind of assignment too

*Optional binding* **is** an unwrapping operation **and** an assignment operation.  It says "if there is a value inside the box, assign it to this new variable and enter the then clause, otherwise proceed to the else clause if it exists".

```
var optionalValue: String? = "hello"

if let value = optionalValue {
    // value is the contents of the box, it has type String
    print("value is \(value)")
} else {
    // the optional binding failed because the box is empty
    print("optionalValue is nil")
}
```

Comment: thanks @vacawama, did you mean optional binding is not a kind of assignment , but a special kind operation( unwrapping operation) ?

Comment: Optional binding is unwrapping **and** assignment. If the optional is not `nil`, it unwraps the optional and assigns the value to a new constant (when you use `if let`) or a new variable (when you use `if var`).

Comment: OK , so it seems that the "if let" should be seem together , i used to understand it as a if statement : if ( let value = optional), this cause the misunderstanding

Comment: It is best to think of `if let` as a unit, because `if (let value = optional)` doesn't compile.  You can do multiple optional bindings in one `if` though:  `if let a = Int("5"), let b = Int("6") { print(a, b) }`

Answer (score 1):

When you `set` an `Optional` property, you do not have to unwrap it.
Unwrapping is required only when assigning an optional value to a non-optional property:

```
var name: String = "" // non-optional
var str: String?

// this will not compile, because you need to unwrap str first
name = str

// this will compile, because we're providing a default value
name = str ?? ""

// this will also compile, because name is not an optional
// it would still compile if name was optional, because str is optional too
str = name
```

Comment: But why Optional binding don't need unwrapping? i think i  if let constantName =  some Optional is kind of assignment too

Comment: That's just how optionals work. The assigned value will be stored as optional anyway, so why require unwrapping?